# I need a substitution for Parmesan cheese

Tags: bread, beer

I am doing bread in a jar for a gift basket. It calls for Parmesan cheese(beer bread)  what can i use for replacement if i have no Parmesan cheese. Is it necessary to add this ingredient?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the recipe with us? And are we talking about "dry ingredients that the recipient will mix & bake"? Please [edit] your questions with details. Then, while you wait for answers, I suggest you take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about the site. Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/63953/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/37311/67

Comment: yes its all dry mix. flour , corn meal, baking soda & powder, brown sugar, crushed red pepper and minced onion.  . I found recipe at budget101.com.  thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I know the title of the other question says "cheaper" but it lists a ton of substitutes of different price classes, and you are unlikely to find a more expensive substitute anyway, so it is our canonical parmesan substitute question.

Answer (score 1):

Any hard cheese will/should do.

Something like Pecorino Romano, Asiago or Manchego or dried Monterey Jack can be substituted quite easily.

Heck (heresy) Get some Kraft Parmesan (yes, the cheap stuff in a box).

Other cheeses like Cheddar will melt and change the property of the bread (IMO).

Comment: Did you see my comment? Not all substitutions will work for a dry mix - in fact, the "sawdust" might be the only one that can survive at room temperature... Once OP has clarified, I'll probably upvote.

Comment: no biggie, did not see your comment in time.

Comment: nutritional yeast is also shelf-stable.  I suspect it would work, but I've not played with it enough to know how it behaves in breads.

Comment: @Stephie - Would the recipe tell us anything new? Very hard cheeses like the ones Max listed are fine at room temperature- if they get too warm the fat melts a bit but otherwise they'll stay good for months.

Comment: @Sobachatina yes, it would. But even more so if we knew whether we are talking about a dry mix or sth. baked in a jar. In the latter case, there might be more substitutions possible.